# What's the difference between componentWillMount and UNSAFE_componentWillMount in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

this is [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount).
This lifecycle was previously named componentWillMount. That name will continue to work until version 17. 
But What's the difference between componentWillMount and UNSAFE_componentWillMount in ReactJS.

Comment: Having a link to the UNSAFE_componentWillMount might help us out

Answer (score 11):

Both lifecycle methods do the same in React 16.

The difference is that `componentWillMount` will not exist in future versions of React from version 17 onward.

So if you want your code to work in future versions of React, you have two choices:

1. **Recommended**: use the constructor of the component class instead
2. Use `UNSAFE_componentWillMount`

The lifecycle method was renamed to make sure developers realize that there is a better way than using the `UNSAFE` method.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference other than the name. This method is now legacy and will be deprecated in the future. Actually this name is an alias for the real one. Like, just a warning that using this method is unsafe.

Using both those names work with the current release. In a future release (16.x) there will be a warning in dev mode. In the 17 release without using `UNSAFE` prefix this method won't work.